# how to destroy model but also not allow last role to be removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have a very simple group and role model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  after_destroy :ensure_last_role

  private
  def ensure_last_role
    raise "Can't delete last role" if group.roles.count.zero?
  end  
end
```

The after_destroy works perfectly and doesn't allow the last role to be destroyed by accident.  BUT this also prevents the group from being destroyed when :dependent => :destroy tries to destroy all roles.  Is it possible to not call ensure_last_role when a group gets destroyed or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with this a little while, I settled on a solution that doesn't use the Rails built in `dependent: :destroy` for the relation, as I couldn't get the callbacks to fire in the right order. There were also some issues with caching, so each time you try to destroy a `Role` it will make a small SQL query to see if its group still exists in the database:

```
> role.destroy
  Group Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = 18 LIMIT 1
```

At any rate, here's the full model code:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  after_destroy :destroy_roles

  def destroy_roles
    roles.each { |r| r.destroy }
  end
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  before_destroy :ensure_last_role, if: "Group.exists?(group_id)"

  private

  def ensure_last_role
    raise "Can't delete last role" if group.roles.count == 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, as I think about it, it's possible that this won't work due to the `after_destroy` callback being called on the last `Role` before the `Group` is ever destroyed; I'll add an alternative answer if it doesn't!

Comment: After some fiddling I think I have a decent solution; I've updated the answer.

Comment: that works thanks.  the after_destroy :destroy_roles worries me a little because i assume that if there's a problem destroying a role we'll be left with orphan roles?

Comment: No; Rails wraps the operation in a transaction, so if you raise an exception during the `after_destroy` callback (including the callbacks for the `Role`s), Rails will simply roll back the transaction and the group will not be destroyed.